# (Java) Trouble going between URLs and files with a .jar file

Tags: java, file, url, jframe

I'm making a rather big program in java. It has lots of files, including images, audio, and text files. When I'm running from Eclipse, the code I use works fine. However, I always have trouble gaining access to them from a .jar file that's on its own.

I'll give you an example of how I'm coding this.

For the BufferedImage, I have it this way:

```
File bgImgFile = new File("images/nature.jpg");
BufferedImage bgImg = ImageIO.read(bgImgFile);
```

For the AudioInputStream, I have:

```
File soundFile = new File("audio/two.wav");
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
```

And for the text file, I have:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("scripts/0.txt");
```

This all works fine for when I'm in Eclipse. However, I'm thinking about what I'll want to do for distribution. I want to have a .jar file that can run anywhere, and doesn't need to be in the same directory as those folders containing the files. I've done this before and it's worked fine.

This is what I tried to do for the image:

```
URL bgFileUrl = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/nature.jpg");
File bgImgFile = new File(bgFileUrl.getFile());
BufferedImage bgImg = ImageIO.read(bgImgFile);
```

I did similar things for the audio and text file. However, even when I tried in different combinations of having the files themselves in the same directory, having a slash in front of the plain file name, etc., nothing worked. I want to be able to include these files in the .jar file so I don't have to run the .jar from that specific folder.

One thing I don't understand is that, when I opened up the .jar file made using my original code, the images, audio, and scripts folders were in there and they had my files. They were there. However, when I tried to run it, I got an IIOException ("Can't read input file!") and a NullPointerException, even though I was using the same code as before.

How do I make it so the files are included in the .jar file so it can run on its own?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A "file" inside of a Jar file does not look like a file to the OS.  It's part of a Jar, not a file that can be read separately from your Jar. What you might want is `getResouce()` and `getResourceAsStream()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: Jar is just a simple zip archive with couple of special files added on top. You can easily verify if the files you need are added to your jars by using any zip capable archive viewer (such as winrar). If they are not where you expect them to be, fix your build script (maven, gradle or whatever your ide is using).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
 URL audioFileUrl = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("audio/two.wav"");
 AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFileUrl);
```